# Import multiple txt filex into R

Tags: r, import, append

I want to import multiple .txt files into R. Each file presents one case and in step number two all cases should be integrated in one data frame. With the second step I am having difficulty and would really appreciate help.
So far I have done the following:

```
filenames <- list.files(path="Stroop/.")
stroop <- rep(NA, length(filenames))
i <- 1
for (filename in filenames) {
  print(filename)
  fn <- paste("Stroop",filename,sep="/")
  data <- read.table(fn,stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE,
                     col.names=c("Name" "Kompatibel.korrekt" "Kompatibel.Falsch"    
                     "Inkompatibel.Korrekt" "Inkompatibel.Inkorrekt"    
                     "Dauer.kompatibel" "Dauer.incompatibel"    
                     "Std.kompatibel"   "Std.inkompatibel")
  )
    i <- i + 1
}
```

---

How can I create a dataframe that yields all cases with the 9 variables?
Thank you for your help!!
Johannes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that you are overwriting data each time you iterate through the loop. Consider using the following code instead:

```
filenames <- list.files(path="Stroop/.")
fn <- paste("Stroop",filenames,sep="/")
mylist <- lapply(fn, read.table, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then you can combine all of the dataframes using:

```
do.call(rbind, mylist)
```